# Adding All Numbers In a Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a Array filled with 24 numbers an I would like all the numbers to be added together and then displayed in a text box. This is the code I have created for the array. but I'm not sure how to add all the numbers in the array together. thank You  for Your Time.

```
    'Calculating distances
    Dim Game As String

    Game = txtGameAdd.Text

    SystemValueGame = SystemValueGame + 1
    TotalGames(SystemValueGame) = Game
    txtGameAdd.Text = ""
    txtGameAdd.Focus()

    'Keeping count with lables'

    lblAmountNum.Text = SystemValueGame

    'Double Checking SystemValue'

    If SystemValueGame = 24 Then

        'notify when array is full'

        MsgBox("Entered Max Amount Of Surnames", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

        txtGameAdd.Text = " "
        txtGameAdd.Enabled = False

    End If
```

Comment: Try with [For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement)

Comment: what is the array ?

Comment: The array is TotalGames

Comment: Use `TotalGames.Sum()`

Comment: is that all really. awesome thank you for the life saver.

Comment: I seem to be getting a error with sum.

Comment: You seem to mix strings and integers

Comment: you are storing a string value in your array and then trying to sum it.  you cannot add strings they way you are doing.  first add them as numbers and then sum will work.  your array should be of type integer or decimal\double for sum to work

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something very similar to this.

```
    Dim ar As Array = Nothing
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    For Each st As String In ar
        sum = sum + CInt(st)
    Next
```

A method such as this, will access every value of the array and add them together.